# How to enable Advance Option in BIOS INSYDE F.91?

Tags: windows-10, boot

I have multiboot **hp pavillion ab032tx** model.

I need to turn on system at a specific time

So for that I need the advance option to be enabled in bios of my laptop.

Bios has all the options except Advance Option Settings.

Comment: HP has not offered a "Advanced Option" in their bios in decades. What you see is what you get.

Comment: You don't even have a smartphone / tablet (or router) that probably could send a WOL packet?